# Low ranked master's before PhD

Tags: masters

Is it a bad idea to do a Master's at a low ranked university before doing a PhD, if my undergraduate record is not strong enough for me to be admitted into a good PhD program out of undergrad?

The university I am considering is low ranked in my subject field of interest (70-80). However, the university itself has a strong overall reputation and would be considered a household name (top 30 undergrad USNWR).

I know that I would have some decent research opportunities in the master's, as well as the chance to write a two-semester thesis. However, I am not sure about the prestige of the faculty, and the program is somewhat small.

Comment: Ranked *where*? Worldwide?

Comment: This would be in the graduate subject ranking according to USNWR.

Comment: Would you be happy to live at that place (especially during Covid times, with probably not to many contacts?)? Feeling happy where you live ia much important than any ranking.

Comment: Who or what is USNWR?

Comment: US News and World Report. They do rankings for undergrad as well as many grad programs. I believe when people refer to the "top X schools" in a given graduate discipline they are referring to the USNWR rankings (or just common consensus). At the graduate level I believe the rankings are generated by surveying professors in the field for their impressions of a given program's reputation, so I am pretty sure they reflect the common consensus among the academic community either way.

Comment: @user111388 Yes, I would be happy to live in the area.

Comment: Hmmm, 70-80 is not a _low rank_. But more important, how do you know that you aren't already qualified to apply to a doctoral program - assuming US? A small program might be more of a problem, giving fewer options.

Comment: @Buffy The interesting thing is that I had 0 courses in the discipline I would be doing the master's in in undergrad. Plus 0 research experience. So I don't think I could have put together a convincing doctoral application even if I tried. This program admitted me with a few undergrad prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess that the university in question is still an R1 university (and in the US) and is about mid way through the rankings of those. From that I assume that the standards are high and that you should get a fine education.

And, from comments, you probably need a solid grounding in the new field, so I don't really see any down-side.

A small program can be a bit of a problem, however, if it gives you fewer options. Alternatively, it might also give you the opportunity to work more closely with a faculty member or two rather than being part of the "mob".

However, don't make assumptions about what is required for admission to a US doctoral program. People frequently choose a different field than their undergraduate major. The typical program is heavy on coursework at the start and often not a lot different from what you do in a masters. So, I'd suggest that you get a solid understanding of the real requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, the university itself is R1. I'll continue to look into the program further to make sure that I would have good research opportunities despite the size.